# Как сделать синхронизацию клиента и сервера?

Tags: php, база-данных

Есть два клиентских приложения, которые могут работать локально и с интернетом синхронизируя свою базу с сервером. 
Проблема в том, что если синхронизировать устройство с севером, то информация этого устройства считается актуальной. 
Допустим, был удален элемент 121 тогда он и на сервере удаляется, а если синхронизироваться со вторым клиентом то 121 считается как новый, что не верно, так как он просто удален. 
Как сделать так чтобы данные удалялись и добавлялись корректно как в гугл календарях, например. 
Неужели придётся хранить все время всю историю изменений на сервере.

Comment: Опишите более доступно, чета ничего не понятно. Первый синхронизировался и удалил, потом синхронизировался второй и каким образом он вообще получит 121 элемент если он уже удален? И что за история изменений?

Comment: 121 элемент удален, а на другом клиенте он есть. Как отличить это элемент от нового. Вдруг это новый элемент который создал клиент, хотя на самом деле этот элемент нужно удалить на всех клиентах а не добавлять на север. Единственное решение хранить на сервере историю удаления где будет записано что 121 нужно удалять.

Comment: Так получается что эту историю нужно хранить постоянно, потому что могут быть клиенты которые не синхронизировались давно и на них много лишнего мусора.

Comment: По факту что такое синхронизация: если данные актуальны - ничего не делаем, если наоборот - загружаем с сервера данные. Для проверки актуальности данных можно использовать даже обычное целое число. Устройство А синхронизируется с сервером (число синхронизации - 0). Если устройство А вносит изменения в БД, то это число увеличиваем на 1. Теперь устройство Б, у устройства Б в памяти есть старое число, т.к. это число в любом случае не будет равно числу 1, то происходит синхронизация данных. На пальцах, но понятно.

Comment: у каждого элемента должен быть уникальный ID, так их и отличают кто где и какой.

Comment: они уникальны, но на одном клиенте остался не удаленные элемент который может считаться новым, так как на севере его нет.

Comment: К сожалению без полной видимости всей картины и логики приложения сложно что либо посоветовать, но на вскидку скорее всего придется делать так: если на клиенте в офф-режиме были изменения, то загружать на сервер, а сервер сам должен определить что новое что старое и принять решения.

Comment: в каждой записи добавляем поле "дата создания" (разумеется с временем, как можно точнее). после любой успешной синхронизации на клиенте запоминаем текущую дату как дату синхронизации (или для надежности храним ее на сервере для каждого клиента). Не воссаздоем на сервере элементы у которых дата создания меньше даты последней синхронизации. Если ID записей всегда растут, то можно помнить последний id который был при синхронизации и работать по ним

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока только так, но историю удаления приходится хранить на сервере постоянно.

Comment: А чем идея с датами не понравилась ? По моему дата изменения и дата создания решают все проблемы и никаких логов не надо

Comment: только это не решает проблему удаления

Comment: Почему ? Если дата создания записи оказалась меньше, чем дата последней синхронизации, а на сервере этой записи нет, значит на севере она была удалена, так как если бы она создалась на клиенте после синхронизации (т.е. была бы действительно новой) то у нее дата создания была бы больше чем последней синхронизации

Comment: Клиентов то несколько

Comment: Но, как я сказал в комментарии под вопросом, мы должны хранить дату последней синхронизации для каждого клиента отдельно (на самом клиенте или на сервере, в привязке к клиенту). И сравниванием мы именно с ней.

Comment: а как я тебе клиент то идентифицирую

Comment: Ну в вопросе вы ни слова не сказали, что не можете его идентифицировать. Откуда бы я мог предположить, что его невозможно идентифицировать ... Лично я бы, даже если никакой синхронизации нет, предпочел бы знать о клиентах больше и сделал бы какую нибудь идентификацию. Но если это решительно невозможно, то значит хранить дату синхронизации на клиенте и сообщать ее серверу при подключении. Хотя это конечно не безопасно, клиент может навязать серверу любое поведение. Хотя не индентифицированный клиент вообще может сказать серверу, что я все записи видел и их все у меня удалили, и очистить вам БД

Comment: ты под идентификацие клиента имеешь ввиду устройство ?

Comment: Пользователей много и они имеют ид, также 2 клиента на android или desktop

Comment: может и устройство. А для надежности отдавал бы клиенту некую инфу, которую тот бы хранил бы у себя в БД. В конце концов нас интересует скорее состояние его БД, если по какой то причине железо поменялось, а БД была локально скопирована, то нас будет интересовать именно ее состояние. Вроде как куки в http

Comment: В общем  надо в базе локально хранить какой то постоянный идентификатор устройства, который можно будет сгенерировать  на сервере.

Comment: чтобы сохранять для каждого устройства дату синхронизации свою иначе никак потому что в итоге дата синхронизация устроства должна быть и на сервере